# Get ChartAreas to stack vertically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

I am adding ChartAreas and Series (line type) to a chart dynamically.  Each area has one series.  I am failing to find a way to control how the ChartAreas are displayed inside the chart.

```
<asp:Chart EnableViewState="false" ID="SMDAServerCPUChart" runat="server" 
    Height="650px" Width="1150px" ImageLocation="~/TempImageFiles1"
    ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" Palette="SemiTransparent"
    BorderSkin-SkinStyle="Emboss" BackColor="#DDDDDD" BorderSkin-PageColor="#efeeef">
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="ServerLegend" BackColor="Transparent" 
            Alignment="Center" IsDockedInsideChartArea="False" Docking="Top" />
    </Legends>
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Name="SM/DA CPU Utilization" Text="SM/DA CPU Utilization"
            Font="Verdana, 12pt, style=Bold"></asp:Title>
    </Titles>
</asp:Chart>
```

If I add three areas/series, each takes up the full width of the chart and they are stacked vertically like this:

```
Figure A
--------------------------------------------------------
|                       ChartArea/Series               |
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
|                       ChartArea/Series               |
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
|                       ChartArea/Series               |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I add four, it puts two on top and two on bottom:

```
Figure B
----------------------------        ----------------------------
|     ChartArea/Series     |        |     ChartArea/Series     |
----------------------------        ----------------------------
----------------------------        ----------------------------
|     ChartArea/Series     |        |     ChartArea/Series     |
----------------------------        ----------------------------
```

I have been trying to find how to specify the width of the series, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that.  The Series.AlignmentOrientation property doesn't seem to do anything to help.  I have been playing with PixelPointWidth and such, but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

I want the series to be the full width of the chart and stack vertically, as in Figure A above.

**Update:** I have found that `Chart.ChartAreas(0).Position.Width = 95` will control the ChartArea width as a percentage of the Chart.  However, once that is set, the other position properties have to be set as well, or the charts are overlayed all at the same position.  At this point I assume I will be able to use this--just a lot more coding than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what I came up with.  Comments are inline to explain

```
Sub SizeChartAreas(Ch As System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)

    'Get the number of ChartAreas, and add 1 to account for the title
    'and legend at the top
    Dim NumAreas = Ch.ChartAreas.Count + 1

    'Since the position values are percentages of the ChartArea,
    '(100 / [number of series]) is the basic formula for incrementing
    'the value that specifies the top (Y).  Subtract 5 on the first
    'calculation to snug up some empty space that is otherwise left
    'between the title/legend and first series.
    Dim SumOfHeights As Integer = (100 / NumAreas) - 5

    'Iterate through each ChartArea
    For Each Area As System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea In Ch.ChartAreas

        'Set the width to 95% of the chart width
        Area.Position.Width = 95

        'Set the height to 100 / NumAreas
        Area.Position.Height = 100 / NumAreas

        'Set the left edge at 1% of the width
        Area.Position.X = 1

        'Set the top edge to SumOfHeights
        Area.Position.Y = SumOfHeights

        'Add the height of a series to SumOfHeights
        SumOfHeights += 100 / NumAreas

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

C# implementation using the same general principal that I ended up using.

```
var h = 0;
var total = chart1.ChartAreas.Count;
var part = 100 / total;
foreach (var area in chart1.ChartAreas) {
    area.Position.Auto = false;
    area.Position.Width = 95;
    area.Position.Height = part;
    area.Position.X = 1;
    area.Position.Y = h;                
    h += part;                
}
```